# How to design an Access Control system that is quick to implement and understand, yet maintainable and flexible enough?

Tags: access-control, permissions, rbac, abac

We're currently redesigning our access control system for our SaaS startup (over the past two years it has grown alongside the business and decided to clean it up at this point). The access control system should serve customers with 500 - 10,000 users each.

It should support:

1. Read-only users (i.e. some users may only log in and view items)
2. Only a few users may change global settings (like managing integrations, billing information etc.)
3. Only a few users may change settings for one of our three product modules
4. For each created resource (e.g. a project, a team, ...), only the project members / team members may change the resource.
5. By default, all users may view all projects, but it should be possible to "hide" projects so that only the project members may view the hidden project.

The challenge now is that Role-Based Access Control only seems to satisfy 1-3, but not 4 or 5. Is ABAC now the way to go?

Overall, I think we have similar requirements to JIRA which seem to offer an extremely flexible but also very complex (unintuitive) permission system

Do you have any recommendations on how to best design an Access Control system, i.e. what questions we should ask ourselves and which trade-offs we'll probably have to make?

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of answers you're looking for here. How do you design such a system? Your requirements are fairly clear, so it seems it is already designed. Now you just need your engineers to build it. What trade-offs will you face? Having your engineers take the time to build something takes time and money where they won't be doing other things.

Comment: You might want to explore `Role-centric Attribute Based Access Control`. Described in (among others) [A paper by Jin et al.](https://profsandhu.com/cs5323_s17/mmm-acns12-rabac-paper.pdf).

Comment: For those who design ABAC but not implement XACML : According to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_access_control#Components), policies can be defined at different levels. In your case, there could be project-level policy (e.g. project XYZ is visible to everyone or member-only) or user-level policy (e.g. the user Alice can edit billing info of project XYZ), or other levels of policies. So your implementation prioritizes all these different levels of policies to determine whether to allow / deny requested operation.

Answer (score 1):

## Background

The other comments and answers as well as your post point you in the right direction. You need a framework that is flexible enough to address your current authorization needs as well as future ones. That framework (or model) is indeed Attribute Based Access Control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)). It's also known as dynamic authorization management and policy-based access control. Gartner, Kuppinger Cole, and Axiomatics (where I work) all have written extensively on the topic:

- [Why we need Dynamic Authorization Management](https://www.kuppingercole.com/blog/kuppinger/why-we-need-dynamic-authorization-management) (2013|Kuppinger Cole)
- [Technology Overview for Externalized Authorization Management](https://www.gartner.com/en/documents/2358815/technology-overview-for-externalized-authorization-manag) (2013|Gartner)
- [Attribute-Based Access Control](https://www.axiomatics.com/attribute-based-access-control/) (2018|Axiomatics)
- [Attribute Based Access Control](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Attribute-Based-Access-Control) (2016|NIST)

That said, given your requirements, ABAC only solves half the equation: the authorization policies and logic. It does not solve the attribute management. You still need to think about metadata or attributes of your users or resources (the projects in your case) that will drive the authorization policies you have.

## Your use cases

> Read-only users (i.e. some users may only log in and view items)

You would need to define a persona or role that you can assign to users to denote they are read-only. Maybe it's the baseline role in your system. Maybe it's the absence of the role but the fact you successfully authenticated.

> Only a few users may change global settings (like managing
>   integrations, billing information etc.)

What makes these users special? A role e.g. "administrator" or "superuser"? You need to define that and you need a process to assign that role to users.

> Only a few users may change settings for one of our three product modules

Same story as above.

> For each created resource (e.g. a project, a team, ...), only the project members / team members may change the resource.

Like you said yourself, this is spot-on ABAC. You would need to write a simple policy (or rule - the words are interchangeable) that states (pseudocode - you could [use ALFA too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML))):

```
A user with role=="..." can do action=="edit" on object of type=="record" if record.assignedProject == user.assignedProject.
```

> By default, all users may view all projects, but it should be possible to "hide" projects so that only the project members may view the hidden project.

See below for an example in ALFA

## Enforcing ABAC

Thinking policies and use cases is great but you also need to think about the enforcement of the decisions. ABAC has a notion of a Policy Enforcement Point (PEP) and Policy Decision Point (PDP). The PEP is where the rubber hits the road: what are you protecting? A web portal? A business process? An API? Either way you need to have a PEP or interceptor in place capable of applying the right authorization. Here's what the architecture looks like from a high-level:

[image: Axiomatics Attribute Based Access Control Architecture & Flow]

## Sample ALFA Code

ALFA, the abbreviated language for authorization is one of the two main standards for authorization along with XACML. ALFA is a simplified notation of the same model XACML follows (policy set, policy, rule). I wrote some samples based on your use case:

```
namespace com.axiomatics.examples{
    /**
     * Projects
     */
     policyset projects{
         target clause objectType == "project"
         apply firstApplicable
         /**
          * View Projects
          */
         policy viewProjects{
             target clause action == "view"
             apply firstApplicable
             /** Anyone can view a project */
             rule viewVisibleProjects{
                 target clause project.hidden == false
                 permit
             }
             /**
              * Only members can view hidden projects - it should be possible to "hide" projects so that only the project members may view the hidden project.
              */
              rule viewHiddenProjects{
                  target clause project.hidden == true
                  permit
                  condition stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(user.name, project.members)
              }
         }
     }

     /**
      * For each created resource (e.g. a project, a team, ...), only the project members / team members may change the resource.
      */
      policyset records{
         target clause objectType == "record"
         apply firstApplicable
         /**
          * Edit records
          */
         policy editRecord{
             target clause action == "edit"
             apply firstApplicable
             /** Project members can edit a record in their project */
             rule viewVisibleProjects{
                 permit
                 condition record.project == user.assignedProject
             }
         }          
      }

     /**
      * Global settings - Only a few users may change global settings (like managing integrations, billing information etc.)
      */
     policy globalSettings{
         target clause objectType == "global settings"
         apply firstApplicable
         /**
          * Administrators can view and change global settings
          */
         rule administrators{
             target clause user.role=="administrator"
                     clause action=="view" or action=="edit"
             permit
         }
     }
}
```

## Implementations

There are several good implementations of ABAC out there:

- Open-source

  - AuthZForce provides you with a XACML-conformant authorization engine
  - Open Policy Agent (OPA) provides you with a REGO-conformant authorization engine. OPA focuses on infrastructure (Kubernetes, Istio...)
- Commercial

  - Axiomatics (where I work) is possibly the oldest company in the list. We've been implementing ABAC since 2006. Everything's based on XACML and ALFA and we can apply authorization to portals, APIs, and databases.
  - Oracle, IBM, and other large vendors also have their own solutions.

Comment: +1. Could you maybe highlight your affiliation a bit more? Right now it is hidden somewhere mid-sentence.

Comment: You're using and referencing axiomatics throughout. I would put a disclaimer at the top for clarity.

Comment: I do add a disclaimer! None of what I wrote is specific to Axiomatics. It's all standards-based

Comment: Are there cloud based auth servers that do this, e.g. auth0?

Comment: Not that I know - Auth0 does have some policy-based capabilities (Javascript-based rules) but they tend to be about authentication mainly. Cloud-based API gateways come close too (Mulesoft for instance or Apigee)

Answer (score 0):

You can create permissions like:

- View assigned projects
- Edit assigned projects
- View non-hidden projects
- View all projects

From a user's point of view this is quite simple and understandable. From the developer's point of view, checking permissions is a bit more complicated, but still manageable.

If you do this then you are technically doing ABAC, as these permissions are more dynamic than fixed roles. But it will still look very much like RBAC.